# Camera preview stretched

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, android-view

I'm trying to create a custom camera preview activity, but as my camera preview view is not matches the screen height the cam preview is being shrinked and looks bad. Can someone help me and tell me how can I fix this?

Here is how it looks:

[image]

And my code:

```
public class CaptureFly extends Activity implements PictureCallback {
    private ImageButton takePicture;
        private ToggleButton flashOnOff;

        private Camera camera;
        private CameraPreview cameraPreview;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.take_photo);

            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            flashOnOff = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.capture_flash);
            takePicture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.capture_btn);

            camera = CameraHelper.getCameraInstance();
            if (CameraHelper.cameraAvailable(camera)) {
                initCameraPreview();
            }

            flashOnOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    // stopPreview();

                }
            });
            takePicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, CaptureFly.this);
                }
            });
            initActionbar();
        }

        // Show the camera view on the activity
        private void initCameraPreview() {
            cameraPreview = (CameraPreview) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            cameraPreview.init(camera);
        }

        private static String savePictureToFileSystem(byte[] data) {
            File file = MediaHelper.getOutputMediaFile();
            MediaHelper.saveToFile(data, file);
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        }

        private void setResult(String path) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CaptureFly.this, FlyPreview.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_IMAGE_PATH, path);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        // ALWAYS remember to release the camera when you are finished
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            releaseCamera();
        }

        private void releaseCamera() {
            if (camera != null) {
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
            }
        }

        private void initActionbar() {
            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nav_bg));
            // adds a back button
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.exit_ex);
            int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id",
                    "android");
            TextView abTitle = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
            Typeface mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "rockwell.ttf");
            abTitle.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
            abTitle.setTypeface(mTypeface);
            abTitle.setText(getString(R.string.capture_an_image));
            abTitle.setTextSize(20);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.v("--", "Picture taken");
            String path = savePictureToFileSystem(data);
            setResult(path);
            finish();
        }
```

XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="11" >

    <com.flyflasher.views.CameraPreview
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/capture_browse"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/browse"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/browse_" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/capture_flash"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flash_on"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:textOff="@string/flash_off"
            android:textOn="@string/flash_on" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="#272721"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/capture_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/capture_btn" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share layout.xml

Comment: It is happening because you set layout weight as 5. Your entire screen is divided by the weight you give (here 11). Out of 11, you gave 5 for ImageView. You have to increase weight for Imageview. Again you can reduce weight of last linear layout (the one with Image button)

Comment: @Paritosh yes but that way I will lose the layout looks.. there must be another solution

Comment: For maintaining ratio, we have to reduce width.

Comment: Is that black space below.buttons intended?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the display orientation of the camera by callind [camera.setDisplayOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)) method. You can find the details in android docs.
Doing this it will also show the display a little squeezed based on the difference between the aspect ratios of the screen and camera preview size. So you may need to adjust the SurfaceView size accordingly. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580887/android-camera-stretched-in-landscape-mode)